# Angularjs templates from map

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angularjs, is there a way by which i can keep all my templates in a map. and access them as needed.

```
  <li  class="commentList" ng-repeat="c in m.c"
     ng-include="'template1.html'">
  </li>
```

from `ng-repeat="c in m.c"` based on `c.type` i want to load a different type of template.
Hence i like to keep a map of c.type to template :

```
{'type1':'<script type="text/ng-template" id="template1.html"> <div class="col1">..T1.</div></script>',
'type2':''<script type="text/ng-template" id="template2.html"> <div class="col3">..T2.</div></script>'}
```

Comment: you can keep all template in a map. you can parse any string format into template. anotyer way is to use $templateCache.get('key'). or do you have problem compileing a template?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your HTML code should do, but probably this could help you:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .run(function ($templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put(
            'tmpl1.html', angular.element('#tmpl1.html').html());
        $templateCache.put(
            'tmpl2.html', angular.element('#tmpl2.html').html());
    });
```

In your case you have to adopt the above code to cosume your map. If you want to register the template by `type1` (the key), it's easy. But if you want to use `template1.html` you will have to either change the key of the map or extract the id with regular expression.

There is as well a grunt plugin which generates a JS file with all your templates: [grunt-html2js](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-html2js).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

store the name of templates file in an array

```
<li  class="commentList" ng-repeat="c in m.c">
<load-templates item="c"></load-templates>
</li>
```

and the js

```
appname.directive('loadTemplates', function ($compile, $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        link: function ($scope, $element) {
            $http.get('path to template/'+$scope.item+'.html').success(function (html) {
                $element.html(html).show();
                $compile($element.contents())($scope);
                // if you wish to do some other functions on the templates goes here 
            });
        },
        scope: {
            item: '='
        }
    }
});
```